# Method to solve the stated recurrence?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, master-theorem

Need help finding a method for solving the following:
Given `f(n)` to be `9f(n/3)+(n2)*(log3n)` for all `n > 1`.
And given `f(1)=1`.
Solve for `f(n)`
I tried the master theorem, but all the 3 cases did not fit here, my guess would be using the substitution method, but I am not sure how to apply it

Comment: All these questions about solving recurrences which are currently in play.  Methinks someone in a class somewhere has suggested to classmates that SO is a good place to go for help with homework. Sometimes it is.

Comment: Because number of this questions increased I suggest to vote close all of them.

Comment: You can think about your problem yourself and talk with your classmates and finally check your solution with Wolframalpha, your current problem is simply solvable with Master theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the substitution `f(n) = n2g(n)`.

This gives us `g(n) = g(n/3) + log n`.

And so `g(n) = Θ(log2n)` and `f(n) = Θ(n2log2n)`